# Calculate Price of items in a list

Tags: list, haskell, algebraic-data-types

I am learning algebraic-data-types in Haskell, and I ran into a problem I cannot solve.

So I want to enter a list of groceries, and as an output I should get the total price.

For now, I have the types:

```
data Item = A | B | C deriving (Eq, Show)
data List = Empty | Add Item List
```

and I have the groceries list: `` list1 = A `Add` (B `Add` Empty) ``

I have a function (That sets the prices of the items):

```
p:: Item -> Int
p A = 2
p B = 4
p C = 5
```

And now here is where I have a difficulty.
I want to apply the function "p" to my list1. But I am not sure how.

Here is my current code:

```
price:: (Item -> Int) -> List -> Int
price p (Add x xs)
    | x == A = A + price xs
    | x == B = B + price xs
    | x == C = C + price xs
    | otherwise = 0
```

I also tried this.

```
price:: (Item -> Int) -> List -> Int
price p (Add x xs) = x + price xs
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide your whole implementation ? We don't have 'Join' to create the list and try

Comment: What’s `Join`? Do you mean `Add`? In `price`, you’re not using the `p` function anywhere, you may want to start with fixing that.

Comment: Yes the `Join` should be `Add`

My bad

Comment: `List` is basically the same as the built-in `[Item]` type. You just renamed the data constructor `[]` to `Empty` and `(:)` to `Add`. (`List`, unlike `[]`, is not parameterized.)

Comment: I.e., `[]` is *already* an algebraic data type,  like every other type in Haskell. (It's not so much that algebraic data types are a special kind of Haskell type, rather Haskell's type system is built around the notion of algebraic data types.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`price`'s first parameter is a function which accepts `List` parameter and returns `Int` (like the declared `p` function, but do not confuse it with `p` parameter in `price p (Add x xs)` pattern, I renamed the former one for clarity to `c`), so the implementation can look like the following:

```hs
price :: (Item -> Int) -> List -> Int
price _ Empty = 0 -- match empty List
price c (Add x xs) = (c x) + price c xs -- match non-empty and perform recursive call to price
```

With call looking like `price p $ Add A Empty` (calculates price of list of one A).

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
What does the "c" mean?

Comment: @RLP see the update, it is name for function calculating single item price (`(Item -> Int)`) parameter in this pattern.

Comment: Is it possible to use the dollar sign within the function?

So you don't have to use it in the input

Comment: @RLP `$` is used as convenient method to provide parameters to the function, you don't need it per se, in this particular case it is needed to separate the parameters so compiler can process them correctly (you can rewrite it as `price p (Add A Empty)`, or just `price p l` if `l` is was a declared earlier `List`)

Comment: As an exercise, you might want to try writing `mapList :: (Item -> b) -> List -> [b]`, analogous to `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, so that you could have defined `price :: (Item -> Int) -> List -> Int` as `price p xs = sum (mapList p xs)`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to chepner's suggestion to implement `mapList` I might suggest writing `foldrList`.

```
foldrList _ i Empty = i
foldrList f i (Add x xs) = f x (foldrList f i xs)
```

Having done so, the total price of a list of items can be calculated:

```
totalPrice items = foldrList (\item acc -> p item + acc) 0 items
```

Or simply:

```
totalPrice = foldrList (\item acc -> p item + acc) 0
```